# Filesystem for web developing

Tags: linux, filesystems, web, arch-linux

My distro is ArchLinux. I have an empty HDD I would like to mount at `/srv`. What is the best filesystem for storing projects (PHP, Zend Framework, many files up to 100 kB but they may be bigger - images or small video files)?

Comment: Any of them. Chose just one.

Comment: @mailq: +1. Plus that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Don't worry. This questions is going to be closed...

Comment: Oh come on, ReiserFS for the win.

Comment: When in doubt, you should simply stick with the distribution defaults for these types of things.  They wouldn't be defaults if they didn't provide adequate performance in the vast majority of the use-cases.

Comment: Ok. I heard ReiserFS is good for small files and I just wanted to know whether this case has best way. Thanks

Comment: @DmitryTeplyakov: For Web development, you're overthinking the problem. The choice of Linux filesystem really doesn't matter much for a small development server . A discussion of filesystems is usually reserved for systems which have special requirements (such as high performance or a dev server with many users). If BTRFS or ZFS were well supported in Linux, then those would be a good choice for development because they support filesystem snapshots (Very handy if users are constantly adding/changing/deleting files). But neither BTRFS or ZFS are well supported on Linux currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest ext filesystem that your distro will support should work just fine.